# RxJava and Network Call Giving "Too many open files error"

Tags: android, jsoup, rx-java

I am trying to get **Instagram** usernames of certain celebrities. I have names of those celebrities and from those names, I want to search Google and get the **username** from the search result. I don't want to use either Google or Instagram API that requires registration and has so many limitations.

So I am just brute-forcing these searches (say 1000 celebrities). After getting celebrity usernames I am saving it in **Firebase**

This is how I am doing.

Below function just searches the **name + "official instagram"** in Google and gets the first result and first header.

```
private fun googleSearch(name: String): Observable<String> {
    return Observable.fromCallable {
        val strUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=$name+official+instagram"
        val doc = Jsoup.connect(strUrl).get()
        val table = doc!!.select("h3")
        table.first().text()
    }
}
```

Below is the iteration that I am running for 1000 users.

```
disposable.add(Observable.just(users)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap { users: MutableList<User> -> Observable.fromIterable(users) }
        .flatMap( { user: User -> googleSearch(user.name))},
                {user: User, username: String -> Pair(user, username)}
        )
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{ pair ->
            val username = pair.second
            val user = pair.first
            if (username.contains("Instagram photos")){
                firebaseRootRef.child(user.id).child("instagramId").setValue(extractInstagUsername(username))
            }
        })
```

Below function is just getting the exact username from the search result.

```
private fun extractInstagUsername(title: String): String {
    return StringUtils.substringBetween(title, "@", ")")
}
```

When I run the code, it is running for like 30-40 users but then crashing with error

> E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files

What I am missing and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this error relates to Firebase. If you remove the call to Firebase, does the error stay?

Comment: Without firebase, it goes until like 100 and then crashes

Comment: Maybe something is leaking file handles or you forgot to close some resource outside this example code. Also it is possible file handles are not recycled fast enough by the OS/GC.

Comment: for `disposable`, it's a single stream that I don't need to dispose. I am guessing it's `jsoup` making problem, but I believe jsoup closes connection itself and doesn't have a method to close manually. Other than these I don't see any anything needs to be closed. Or as you said if it's not recycled fast enough by OS/GC, any suggestions to improve?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do I have to do firebase calls in a background thread? Because I am getting `I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` which I suppose coming from `firebase`?

Comment: @musooff: if the crash still happens without Firebase, the problems seems unrelated to Firebase. I'm going to remove the Firebase tag from the question. This approach is your best bet to finding the cause of the problem: keep removing bits from the code, until you find the minimal code that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'd also expect the stack trace of the error message to give you a hint as to what exact call is running out of file system handles.

Comment: removing `observeOn` had solved the issue.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.